# ionic 2 Unzip zip file in assets

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, unzip

I did this:

```
this.zip.unzip('../../assets/eval.zip', '../../assets/folder', (progress) => console.log('Unzipping, ' + Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100) + '%'))
     .then((result) => {
      console.log();
       if(result === 0) console.log('SUCCESS');
       if(result === -1) console.log('FAILED');
     });
```

i testes it in browser & android but it always "FAILED";

Answer (score 0):

Run it on android device and see the log on android studio device logging tool (android device monitor). You will find the exact cause of the error.
I had this error. The cause was ionic couldn't find the specified folder so i used this.file.externalDataDirectory or the directory you chose in a format like
"file:///storage/emulated/0/yourPath".

```
// this.import(this.file.externalDataDirectory + '/Spark.epub', this.file.externalDataDirectory + '/spark');

this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalDataDirectory +'assets/folder','')
      .then(_ => {
      this.file.checkFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory +'assets/eval.zip','')
      .then(_ => {
      this.zip.unzip(this.file.externalDataDirectory +'assets/eval.zip', this.file.externalDataDirectory +'assets/folder', 
      (progress) => console.log('Unzipping, ' + Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100) + '%'))
      .then((data) => {
        /* Wow everything goes good, but just in case verify data.success */
        console.log(data);
      }).then((error) => {
          /* Wow something goes wrong, check the error.message */
          console.log(error);
          debugger;
      })
      }).catch(err => console.log('file doesn\'t exist'));
      }).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesn\'t exist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that you cannot unzip from `www/assets` folder, you need to copy that zip file into system directory of the device like **this.file.dataDirectory**, then execute unzip in here.

I've tested, it works.

Reference: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip/issues/56